# Expectation of a sequence of gaussian variables

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Suppose we are given a sequence of iid Gaussian random variables $\{x_k \}$ with zero mean and unit variance. We create a new random variable $$X_n = e^{\sum_{n\ge k}x_k}.$$ How does one go about calculating the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$? I know that by definition that the expectation of a random variable $Y$ is  $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int Y(\omega)\mathbb{P}(d\omega) $$ however, I am less clear on how to properly set up this integral in the case of the expectation of $X_n$, as it was created from $n$ random variables $x_k$.

Comment: You are asking how to obtain the mean of a lognormal distribution.  See, *inter alia*, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174449/can-i-get-the-parameters-of-a-lognormal-distribution-from-the-sample-mean-medi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- You should be able to find the mean and variance of the sum $S$ of $n$ independent random variables with standard normal distributions; it too will have a normal distribution.
- So you should be able to state the probability density function $f(s)$ for $S$
- You want to find $$\mathbb E\left[e^S\right] = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^s f(s)\, ds$$ which should not be too difficult if you complete the square inside the exponential
- There may be shortcuts, either using the moment generating function of a normal distribution or the mean of a lognormal distribution

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the hints and clearing up my thinking. I appreciate it.