# Variance of the method of moments estimator for $\mu$ of log-normal distribution

Tags: variance, estimators, lognormal-distribution, method-of-moments

Suppose the data has originated from a log-normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (i.e. the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution). I have only the sample mean and sample variance of the data (but not of the logged-data).

Method of moments can be used to produce an estimator for $\mu$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters)) but is there a proper way of estimating the variance of this estimator (or simply producing a confidence interval for $\mu$)? The fact that the estimator is not very well behaved has been noted (see e.g. [comment to a previous CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26608/how-do-i-estimate-the-parameters-of-a-log-normal-distribution-from-the-sample-me) or [subsection 3.2.2 of a Masters Thesis](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2927&context=etd)).